# How to load an XML file with multiple same name elements into a database using an SSIS package

Tags: xml, ssis, tags, load

I am struggling to load the xml onto database having multiple elements in a single node :

Example :

```
<EMPLS>
  <EMPL>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <NAME>ALPHA</NAME>
    <HOBBY>H1</HOBBY>
    <HOBBY>H1</HOBBY>
  </EMPL>
</EMPLS>
```

In XSD 3 occurrences of the element are permissible.

I am using XML Source to populate my Database. It's intelligent enough to recognize XML in two parts one for the EMPLS record and another for HOBBY as it allows multiple occurrences as per xsd.

The issue is that the package is populating two records for the node having multiple occurrences of HOBBY wherein the desired behavior I would like to obtain is single record for each EMPL getting inserted irrespective of number of occurrences of HOBBY and  for multiple HOBBY tags a concatenated value separated by a Comma(may be) should get inserted.